# Node certificate vs admin certificate

Tags: certificates

I tried to understand what is the difference between node and admin certificate.
Admin certificate is like root and the node certificate is just for communication with others nodes?

Comment: Where did you see the term "admin certificate" being used? The canonical names are "Certificate Authority", "Intermediate Certificate" and "Server Certificate".

Comment: I think this question is missing the information in which context you have something like "node and admin" certificates. Can you provide a source where these terms are being used and which you are trying to understand?

Comment: Wait, you're talking about Elastic,aren't you ... https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/security-configuration/generate-certificates/#generate-an-admin-certificate

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for: https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/security-configuration/tls/#configure-node-certificates

Comment: Yes thanks, i didn't know that is from elastic, i was thinking is from kubernetes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from:  https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6253/schroeder

**Configure node certificates**

> The Security plugin needs to identify inter-cluster requests (i.e.
>   requests between the nodes). The simplest way of configuring node
>   certificates is to list the Distinguished Names (DNs) of these
>   certificates in elasticsearch.yml. All DNs must be included in
>   elasticsearch.yml on all nodes.

**Configure admin certificates**

> Admin certificates are regular client certificates that have elevated
>   rights to perform administrative tasks. You need an admin certificate
>   to change the the Security plugin configuration using
>   plugins/opendistro_security/tools/securityadmin.sh or the REST API.

https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/security-configuration/tls/#configure-node-certificates

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea if the link is correct. You provided no context to your question or what you were talking about.